# is it advised to created two separate indexes for the query to filter on one field and sort on another?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-indexes

I have a query that's something like the following

```
find( { a : { $gt: 3 } } ).sort( { b : -1 } )
```

Is it advised to create an index for field a and b separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, with [compound](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-CompoundKeysIndexes) index query will work faster:

```
db.items.ensureIndex({a:1, b:-1});
```

Also you can make sure that your query use index with [explain](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Optimization#Optimization-Explain) command.

Comment: Thanks! When using Morphia, how could I define a compound index for a geo field and another field (a counter field)? Currently I have a @Indexed(value=IndexDirection.GEO2D) annotation for the geo field and a @Indexed(value=IndexDirection.DESC) for the other field?

Comment: @tom: Create [compound index](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-CompoundIndexes): `db.places.ensureIndex( { location : "2d" , counter : -1 } );` and make sure that it work with `explain` command.